# Not appearing vertical lines in table

Tags: tables

I'm having weird problem of not having vertical lines in my table. Im writing my master thesis using template provided by my university therefore I'm not sure if they had changed something. Packages I have imported so far:

```
\documentclass[magisterska, english]{pwr_wmat_praca_dyplomowa}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{svg}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\graphicspath{{./Figures/},{../Figures/},{./Pictures/}}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}
%\usepackage{filecontents}%%Do tworzenia pliku cytowanych prac
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,lined,boxed,commentsnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{geometry}


\RequirePackage[hyperpageref=true]{backref} 
    \renewcommand*{\backreflastsep}{, }
        \renewcommand*{\backreftwosep}{, }
        
    \renewcommand*{\backref}[1]{}  
    \renewcommand*{\backrefalt}[4]{
       \ifcase #1 
          Not cited.
       \or
          Cited on #2.
       \else
          Cited on #2.
       \fi}


\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Twierdzenie}
\numberwithin{theorem}{chapter}
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemat} 
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Wniosek}
\newtheorem{fact}[theorem]{Fakt}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\numberwithin{theorem}{chapter}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definicja} 
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Przykład}
\newtheorem{note}[theorem]{Uwaga}

\def\O{\mathcal{O}}
\def\Q{\mathcal{Q}}

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
```

and the code:

```
\begin{table}[H]\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c}
    & 1st Peak 49\% & 2nd Peak & 3rd Peak \\
    \hline
    Random Bot          & 82\%      &   72\%        &x\\
    Minimax Bot $d=1$   & 61\%      &     16\%      &x\\
    Minimax Bot $d=2$   & 4\%      &    x       &x\\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image: table]

Comment: If all I do is put `\documentclass{article}` at the start of that and wrap the table code in `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}` the vertical lines are there, so it's very likely that the problem is caused by code you're not including, like your documentclass or something in between the part of the preamble you posted and the table. It's always best to post a single, complete but minimal document that can be compiled as is to show the problem.

Comment: please provide a example that shows the problem

Comment: why specify amsmath 3 times (plus mathtools which also loads it) and caption and subcaption and geometry twice each

Comment: @David Carlisle I think this is not the actual OP's preamble, but rather just grabbing or copy-pasting the loaded packages to show us here. Of course the best is to show us a complete MWE as noted.

Comment: @Saguro Can you show us the code the produced the output image that you posted in your question?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle
@hesham
I edited and added everything that is above `\begin{document}`. As I said the template comes from my University `\documentclass[magisterska, english]{pwr_wmat_praca_dyplomowa}` therefore I'm not sure what else can I add to the question to clarify or help you find the reason of my problem

Comment: Well in that case we probably can't find the reason of your problem, then.

Comment: Is your University's document class available online somewhere? Even with the new code, if I just make it `report`, the lines are there, so it would seem to be something in the document class. You may need to ask them for help if you can't distribute it. But do clean up your preamble. IMHO with that particular table, however, it looks better without the vertical lines; maybe your University thinks so too...